# Is there any evidence that Cleopatra and Caesarion considered fleeing to India to escape the Romans?

Tags: ancient-rome, ancient-egypt, ancient-india

In a book, [Land of the Seven Rivers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0143420933) by Sanjeev Sanyal, I saw a claim made by the author which says that Cleopatra and her son [Caesarion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesarion) wanted to flee to India to evade Roman arrest. Sanjeev Sanyal goes on to say that [Cleopatra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleopatra) famously poisoned herself and Caesarion was persuaded by traders to not go.

Is there any evidence, archaeological or liturgical, that Cleopatra and her son had planned to escape to India?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The source for [Sanjeev Sanyal's account](https://books.google.com.ph/books?redir_esc=y&id=xu-O9eNmQXMC&q=cleopatra#v=snippet&q=cleopatra&f=false) is most likely [Plutarch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutarch). In his [Life of Anthony](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Plutarch/Lives/Antony*.html), Plutarch wrote:

> Caesarion, who was said to be Cleopatra's son by Julius Caesar, was
>   sent by his mother, with much treasure, into India, by way of
>   Ethiopia. There Rhodon, another tutor like Theodorus, persuaded him to
>   go back, on the ground that Caesar invited him to take the kingdom.

Our sources are somewhat unclear but, putting together what evidence has survived, Michael Gray-Fow's 2014 article *[What to do with Caesarion](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/greece-and-rome/article/what-to-do-with-caesarion/3818DB1417538825458DADCB78B678EF)* in the Classical Society journal *Greece & Rome*, says that Cleopatra, when deciding in 30 BC where to flee,

> … opted for India and organized a fleet on the Red Sea, but it was
>   destroyed by the [Nabateans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nabataeans) because their king Malchus (Maliku II)
>   wanted to demonstrate his value to Octavian…
>   As
>   [Octavian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustus) approached Alexandria, Cleopatra decided that Caesarion’s only salvation lay in getting as
>   far away from Octavian as possible. For him alone she resurrected the
>   idea of flight to India.

Gray-Fow continues:

> Caesarion was sent off up the Nile with his tutor, Rhodon…Octavian
>   entered Alexandria on 1 August 30 BC. Just over a week later,
>   probably believing that Caesarion was safely on his way to India and
>   that Octavian might be more lenient towards him if she were dead,
>   Cleopatra also committed suicide.
>
> It is doubtful whether Caesarion ever reached [Myos Hormos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myos_Hormos) or [Berenice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berenice_Troglodytica) [Red Sea ports].
>   He certainly got no further if he did. Exactly what happened is
>   unclear, perhaps deliberately so. Both Dio and Suetonius agree that
>   Caesarion was overtaken in his flight, though Dio alone implies that
>   he was murdered at that point. Plutarch and Suetonius both claim that
>   Caesarion was brought back to Alexandria and killed there.

Gray-Fow cites numerous sources. Among the primary ones are [Plutarch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutarch) (c. AD 46 – AD 120), [Livy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livy) (64 or 59 BC – AD 12 or 17), [Cassius Dio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassius_Dio) (c. AD 155 – c. AD 235) and [Suetonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suetonius) (c. AD 69 – AD 122).

Answer (score -2):

Please go to this site where you can find more information regarding this matter.
[https://pazhayathu.blogspot.com/2012/08/inorite-blog-cleopatra-and-cheraman.html?m=1#:~:text=Like%20all%20the%20Ptolemies%2C%20Cleopatra,her%20right%20to%20the%20throne](https://pazhayathu.blogspot.com/2012/08/inorite-blog-cleopatra-and-cheraman.html?m=1#:%7E:text=Like%20all%20the%20Ptolemies%2C%20Cleopatra,her%20right%20to%20the%20throne)

Comment: Please avoid posting answers that consist of only a link. What does the article say?